# run-parts ignores jobs.deny

Tags: bash, cron

I use run-parts to run all scripts under a directory,the same way crontab does. But the jobs deny and jobs allow don't block any of the scripts in the directory.

```
rajeevs@rajeev:/home/rajeevs/test$: ls
a
b
jobs.deny

$:cat jobs.deny
a
b

$:run-parts .
hello a
hello b
```

Any idea about this strange behavior?

Comment: Please don't [cross](http://serverfault.com/questions/455197/run-parts-ignores-jobs-deny)-[post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717886/run-parts-ignores-jobs-deny)...

Comment: Are you sure your `run-parts` knows about `jobs.deny`? (Check `man run-parts`.) [Debian's (package `debianutils`) doesn't.](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/debian/utils/run-parts.8)

Answer (score 1):

Run-parts will ignore scripts with "." in their name. 
(Or at least, it did, when i last checked a few years ago)

Please see the man page (or the run-parts script itself) for details.

Comment: The comment on the question is the correct answer.my situation insists in using the allow and deny files.

Comment: Ah, apologies, I completely misread completely your question! I thought you wanted run-parts to run that file instead of taking it into account to deny running the other 2. Sorry! And thanks for that comment.